# Moving wp-content folder to Amazon S3/CloudFront?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to move my wp-content folder to Amazon S3/CloudFront.

I copied the folder to an S3 bucket.

I am in the process of editing the wp-config.php file in order to tell it where to find the moved wp-content folder.

But I am unable to find out which URL to link to?

Do I link to S3 or to CloudFront?

And where do I find the link that I need to enter into wp-config.php?

Answer (score 0):

In order to store the files on S3, you will need to change both the directory location and the URL WordPress renders.

You will need a tool that can map S3 as a local mapped network drive. Check out [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) or [TNT Drive](http://tntdrive.com/). Create a new network drive mapped to S3 using one of these tools.

Include these lines anywhere above the line where WordPress includes the wp-settings.php. Inside your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Mapped/S3Folder/ToBucket/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.domain.com/blog/path/to/wp-content' );
```